# Cross-validation for k-means clustering in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, k-means

I have a dataset of two columns (we can call them x and y).
I understand that for cross-validation I need to split my data into k partitions, and for that the general consensus is that I use createFolds. However, I am a little confused about the output. It seems like I can't use createFolds on my entire dataset, it seems like I have to specify something like **createFolds(data$x, k=5)**. Then I get an output of 5 folds with a row of numbers, and I haven't been able to find documentation on what the output means exactly.

My second question is how to apply cross-validation in R to my test dataset? As I understand it, in R all I need to do to perform k-means clustering on is to specify kmeans(data, centres,...). So if I apply that command to my held-out dataset, how can I use that for cross validation on my test dataset? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think it would help if you would describe more what your actual goal is.

In *supervised learning*, there is always a clear definition of error that quantifies how well $f(X)$ is an approximation of $y$. We can then use cross validation to obtain an estimate o the out-of-sample (or generalization) error of a model. This error we can use to do mode selection.

In *unsupervised learning*, such as clustering, there is usually no clear definition of error. Due to this, also cross-validation cannot be used for this purpose.

However, there are some methods that determine the quality of a clustering via its stability. Here, stability is assessed via cross-validation or bootstrap schemes, see e.g.

[Ben-Hur, Asa, Andre Elisseeff, and Isabelle Guyon. "A stability based method for discovering structure in clustered data." Pacific symposium on biocomputing. Vol. 7. 2001.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Asa_Ben-Hur/publication/11435997_A_Stability_Based_Method_for_Discovering_Structure_in_Clustered_Data/links/00b4953988b6d0233d000000.pdf)

[Tibshirani, Robert, and Guenther Walther. "Cluster validation by prediction strength." Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics 14.3 (2005): 511-528.](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/106186005X59243)

[Fang, Yixin, and Junhui Wang. "Selection of the number of clusters via the bootstrap method." Computational Statistics & Data Analysis 56.3 (2012): 468-477.](http://indigo.lib.uic.edu/bitstream/handle/10027/8612/bootstrap_clustering_revision.pdf?sequence=1)

or

[Haslbeck, J., & Wulff, D. U. (2016). Estimating the Number of Clusters via Normalized Cluster Instability. arXiv preprint arXiv:1608.07494.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09108v1.pdf)

which contains a summary of these approaches.

Answer (score 2):

The `sperrorest` package provides a generic interface for spatial cross-validation in R. The classification tree example here is taken from `?sperrorest`.

Note the partition function `smp.fun = partition.kmeans`. The code syntax used in this example is taken from package version 1.0.0, currently available on Github using `devtools::install_github("pat-s/sperrorest")`.

```
data(ecuador) # Muenchow et al. (2012), see ?ecuador
fo <- slides ~ dem + slope + hcurv + vcurv + log.carea + cslope

# Example of a classification tree fitted to this data:
library(rpart)
ctrl <- rpart.control(cp = 0.005) # show the effects of overfitting
fit <- rpart(fo, data = ecuador, control = ctrl)
par(xpd = TRUE)
plot(fit, compress = TRUE, main = 'Stoyans landslide data set')
text(fit, use.n = TRUE)

# Non-spatial 5-repeated 10-fold cross-validation:
mypred.rpart <- function(object, newdata) predict(object, newdata)[, 2]

# Spatial 5-repeated 10-fold spatial cross-validation:
spres <- sperrorest(data = ecuador, formula = fo,
                    model.fun = rpart, model.args = list(control = ctrl),
                    pred.fun = mypred.rpart,
                    smp.fun = partition.kmeans, 
                    smp.args = list(repetition = 1:5, nfold = 10))
summary(spres$error.rep)
```